# Global variables access problem iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, global-variables

I'm working on a nvaigation-based application and I want to use "global variables" in it.
I used the AppDelegate class, in each view I want to access the variables with I do like the following:

.h

```
@interface Main : UIViewController{
   iMEAppDelegate *datacenter;
}

@property (nonatomc, retain) iMEAppDelegate *datacenter;

@end
```

.m

```
@synthesize dataCenter;

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dataCenter = (iMEAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Now the first time the view appears it's working fine but when navigating to another
one and return back and repress the button that has the below code, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error is thrown:

```
if ([dataCenter.userName isEqualToString:@""]){
SingIn *obj = [[SingIn alloc] initwithNimName:@"SingIn" bundle:nil];
[dataCenter.navController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
[obj release];
```

I'm not sure why is this happening, I'm thinking it may be a memory management issue but I couldn't find a solution to it.

Please help.

Comment: `initwithNimName:bundle:` ? Have you copy and pasted the code or typed it by hand, because it should be `initWithNibName:bundle:`.

Comment: I typed part of it by hand :)

Comment: This question is very specifically related to your circumstances and is unlikely to help anyone in future. You seem confused about basic matters of the language and framework you are using and the compile-time and run-time environments of your code.

Comment: There are no global variables in your example.  Nor did you access any.  So the title is very misleading.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided, my guess for the reason of your EXC_BAD_ACCESS is that you have forgotten to retain your AppDelegate's properties, e.g. dataCenter.userName.

Comment: I guess I did it: 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;

Comment: Then just try to debug it. When you get a crash, grab your call stacks, try to print the value of those variables under suspicion, especially those with nil value.